# Is it possible to pause a job listing on Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs

I've got a job listing running with the standard 30-day term.

I'd like to pause the listing for now because we are about to conduct some interviews and are not interested in any further applicants for the time being.

Currently there doesn't seem to be a pause option. Is there one? Have I missed it?

Can I do something else that is effectively pausing the job listing?

Comment: I wonder if you could just ring SE up and ask, since you are a proper paying customer? That might be easier than awaiting an answer here.

Comment: Come on guys, obviously not a dupe.  Pausing is different than republishing.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I can see why it could be called a dup, he is effectively asking for the same capability.... if he has a potential candidate, he wants to stop the listing but reactivate it if the candidate falls through.   The expiration referenced in the earlier post is a manual early expiration.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks, good point.  I edited the other question's title to better state that.

Comment: I reckon they're dupes, but this question is better phrased. Pausing is more easily grasped as a concept that republishing an expired job listing. So I think this should be considered the canonical question and the other the dupe. I don't know how to make that happen, though!